# Serial console buffer

Tags: linux, console, serial

when i connect to my board through serial console, launch my app which log some events with printf() and close serial console, my app can receive request and send response during a small time and then crash.

This does not append if i keep serial console open.

I suspect the serial console buffer. But maybe i'm wrong.

What do you think ?

Thanks very much
Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

Your application is trying a blocking write to the console, but since you closed your session there is nothing to consume those messages and the application blocks forever.

The easiest way out is to set your serial console to no handshake mode, so that unconsumed log messages are just lost instead of blocking the application.